# WPF Toolkit: display a label above each line in LineSeries Chart

Tags: c#, .net, charts, wpftoolkit, label

I'm trying to display a label on a lineseries in a WPFToolkit chart. The result I'm looking for would be something like this:
[LineSeries with labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cDbo.png)

Is there a way to easily do this?

Comment: Use the Legend property to do that.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I set it to be displayed in the chart window above the line? I can't find a satisfactory property for LegendItemStyle.

Comment: It is possible, but it requires some complex logic to determine x and y coordinates of the label. I think that the legend on the right is a more appropriate solution.

Comment: The legend on the right isn't appropriate for what I want to do. How can I change these x and y coordinates? I just need the name of the property to change, I'll handle the logic of it.